# How can I make a jQuery .each fadeOut AND fadeIn "slider"?

Tags: jquery

I thought I be cheeky and make a "slider" just with `.each`.

It is here: http://liebdich.biz/.

The client wants the effect though like in the original flash animation here: http://blanc-encens.com/.

How can I get the next image (how to use the index here?) to fade in?

Here the code:

```
<style>
ul.list {
list-style-type: none;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.content {
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
top:50%;
height:841px;
margin-top:-420px;
width:1190px;
overflow: hidden;
}

</style>  
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
<ul class="list">
<li><img src="1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {

function fade(){
$('ul.list li').each(function( i ){
    if (i<3) {
        $(this).delay(i*5000).fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
}

setTimeout(fade, 5000); 

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you replicate in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qwLh8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create this effect.

`1.` Put all the image in position absolute with different z-index

`2.` FadeOut() all image one by one until the last

http://jsfiddle.net/gvVaT/1/

**HTML**

```
<img class="imageFade" style="z-index:4" src="http://liebdich.biz/blanc/1.jpg"/>
<img class="imageFade" style="z-index:3" src="http://liebdich.biz/blanc/2.jpg"/>
<img class="imageFade" style="z-index:2" src="http://liebdich.biz/blanc/3.jpg"/>
<img class="imageFade" style="z-index:1" src="http://liebdich.biz/blanc/4.jpg"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageFade{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fade(){
        $('.imageFade').each(function( i ){
            if (i<3) {
                $(this).delay(i*5000).fadeOut(2000);
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(fade, 2000); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. But will I get them to fade in? Ok, I see, you mean the effect of the upcoming picture is like a fade in?

Comment: You made it! Thanks! I was on that path but did not follow it through. I took this approach for the answer, because you took the each, so I can stop at the last picture ( and I do not have to write everything anew ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

I think a better method would be a `setInterval` that swaps the images, something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gdDFe/

```
function swap () {
    var $list = $('ul.list');
    var $next = $('li.active', $list).next('li');

    if (!$next.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    $('li.active', $list).removeClass('active').fadeOut(2000);
    $next.addClass('active').fadeIn(2000);


}

$('ul.list li:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(500);
var interval = setInterval(swap, 5000);
```

---

```
ul.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
}

ul.list li {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Bah. Third time's a charm I think.

Comment: hahaha I think so. You did the exact thing I was trying to do but beat me too it so I was sitting here refreshing waiting for you to get it right

Comment: You basically made it! But how can I stop at the last picture?

Comment: @dollarvar Check my latest edit, with the latest jsfiddle link, that should be addressed.

Comment: Very great job! You pulled it just out of nowhere in no time!! ;) Thanks, but as I said, I did not want to write everything new. Good idea would be copy and paste, but I still have to get through your code, hehe, and I like to understand what I paste. ;) Cheers!!